# Brackets unable to access the extension registry

Tags: adobe-brackets

Everytime I open the extenstion registry, I get this error:

"Unable to access the extension registry. Try again later"

My internet connection is very stable and everything is fine.
Also, I don't see this error with my Macbook, which uses the same wifi connection.
I am now using windows and this error occur.
What should I do? I don't see any clear solution even after searching on google.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 18):

There is a solution!

Copied from a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/brackets/comments/ppb3ow/fix_for_extension_library_the_state_of_brackets/):

---

Hey there,

Brackets is not dead! The only problem on current installations is a broken extension manager functionality. A direct, transparent transfer of the registry to the new domain wasn't possible because of Adobe's implementation of SSL. A quick fix for this is simple, we just have to edit config.json:

- Locate your Brackets installation in your filesystem
- Go to /www/config.json and open it up to edit
- Find this: "extension_registry": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/extend.brackets/registry.json",
- Change to: "extension_registry": "http://registry.brackets.s3.amazonaws.com/registry.json",
- Find this: "extension_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/extend.brackets/{0}/{0}-{1}.zip",
- Change to: "extension_url": "http://registry.brackets.s3.amazonaws.com/{0}-{1}.zip",
- Save and (re)start Brackets, the extension manager should work again

---

I welcome you to see more comments there in the original post.

for my Mac, it was simply this command in the terminal to open the config:

```
open /Applications/Brackets.app/Contents/www/config.json -a Brackets
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Any idea why Brackets doesn't work right off the bat?

Comment: Hi @Will, please read here: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/blog/brackets-text-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Brackets is not being supported anymore, that's why U can't connect  the extenstion registry.

Comment: This is not true. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace config.json on www folder with this [config.json](https://github.com/Ghst-dg/Brackets_Extension_Fix). Do not rename the file just replace at there. Then restart your Brackets Text Editor.
This works for windows

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30471155)